# Add html to a node's title

Tags: 7

I have a Drupal 7 site and I'd like to be able to add an HTML link to part of the title of a node. By default Drupal has this as plain text. Is there any way that I can allow HMTL?

Example:

```
This is a <a href="#">title</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because [`template_process_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_process_page/7) contains the following code.

```
if (!isset($variables['title'])) {
  $variables['title'] = drupal_get_title();
}
```

[`drupal_get_title()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_title/7) calls `check_plain()`.

```
// During a bootstrap, menu.inc is not included and thus we cannot provide a title.
if (!isset($title) && function_exists('menu_get_active_title')) {
  $title = check_plain(menu_get_active_title());
}
```

The only way you have to add HTML to the title is using `hook_preprocess_page()` and set `$variables['title']`.

Keep in mind that `$variables['title']` is also used as value for the `<title>` tag, and [browsers should not expect HTML tags inside that tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-TITLE).

> Titles may contain [character entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/entities.html) (for accented characters, special characters, etc.), but may not contain other markup (including comments).

To change just the node title, you should implement `hook_preprocess_node()` and set `$variables['title']`. By default, [`template_preprocess_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) sets it using `$variables['title'] = check_plain($node->title);`.
As side note, for the node title, Drupal 8 uses `$variables['label']`, not `$variables['title']`.

Comment: I do want to point out that if you remove the checkplain here you may be allowing a xss attack vector. This was the basis of https://www.drupal.org/project/html_title/issues/2968477 which was the security issue that got it shut down back several years ago.

Answer (score 0):

`composer require 'drupal/html_title:^1.4'`
did the trick for me.

The `<br>` tag (which was required for my client's request) was even enabled by default.  Additionally, the `/admin/config/user-interface/html_title` path allows you to enable arbitrary html tags as serves your needs.

I seem unable for some reason to upvote or comment on Toki's answer, so will try this, instead.  Thanks, Toki.  Investigating your response resolved this ticket in about ten minutes, call it 30 minutes total to account for investigation to find your note, and to come back and affirm for others that this module works and is fit for purpose as of drupal 9.3.9.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question and I found a great and simple module [HTML Title.](https://drupal.org/project/html_title) You can enter HTML markups inside your node title and it's done. At least, it was OK for me for italic terms.

EDIT : Indeed my answer deserves a -1, the module is now **obsolete** and creates strange things on node titles, forget it!

Comment: I want to point out that at the time this answer was edited the module did become unsupported. That is no longer the case and is actively maintained. It is a tried and true method that has security coverage.